# Get ID of grouped records in TSQL

Tags: t-sql

**SQL**

```
SELECT ID, AtDate, ItemID, StorageID, TargetItemDocDetailID 
FROM   dbo.ItemBalanceRegisters
```

**Output**

```
 ID,                                       AtDate,                    ItemID, StorageID, TargetItemDocDetailID 

 B363E263-F38B-478F-B8BF-92A0B4C0C11D   2020-05-15 09:41:01.7530061   1   6    NULL

 48EF1748-5459-491E-A84F-AEBF46145217       2020-05-15 11:05:18.7743409   1   9    NULL

 19255F6A-C868-4DEA-8785-D4EF5005B824       2020-05-15 10:24:07.9138724   1   6    NULL
```

I need to get only records with unique fileds: `ItemID, StorageID, TargetItemDocDetailID` and with MAX() date from each group
but also I need to get `ID` if the record in the group.

So my **SQL**

```
SELECT  MAX(AtDate) as AtDate, ItemID, StorageID, TargetItemDocDetailID
FROM  dbo.ItemBalanceRegisters S       
GROUP BY ItemID, StorageID, TargetItemDocDetailID
```

returns

```
 2020-05-15 10:24:07.9138724    1   6   NULL

 2020-05-15 11:05:18.7743409    1   9   NULL
```

and it is fine but I need to see what is `ID` of the record.

So how to inlcude `ID` also into my SQL so it looks like

```
 2020-05-15 10:24:07.9138724    1   6   NULL   19255F6A-C868-4DEA-8785-D4EF5005B824

 2020-05-15 11:05:18.7743409    1   9   NULL   48EF1748-5459-491E-A84F-AEBF46145217
```

Comment: Use `row_number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use beloe query

```
SELECT ID,AtDate,ItemID,StorageID,TargetItemDocDetailID
FROM 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY ItemID, StorageID, TargetItemDocDetailID ORDER BY AtDate DESC) AS RN,*
    FROM TABLE_NAME
)T
WHERE RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
            T1.ID
        ,   T2.*

FROM        dbo.ItemBalanceRegisters    T1
    JOIN    (
                SELECT  
                        AtDate = MAX(AtDate)
                    ,   ItemID
                    ,   StorageID
                    ,   TargetItemDocDetailID
                FROM    dbo.ItemBalanceRegisters S       
                GROUP BY    
                        ItemID
                    ,   StorageID
                    ,   TargetItemDocDetailID
            )   T2  ON
                        T2.ItemID                   =   T1.ItemID                   
                    AND T2.StorageID                =   T1.StorageID                
                    AND T2.TargetItemDocDetailID    =   T1.TargetItemDocDetailID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggravated function in derived table check below the solution hopes help

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7ea32085b5ae791921748f5315f1a790

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN (
    select max(AtDate) maxdate
    ,itemid,storageid,TargetItemDocDetailID FROM mytable 
    group by itemid,storageid,TargetItemDocDetailID
    ) t2 ON t2.itemid = t1.itemid and t2.storageid = t1.storageid and isnull ( t2.TargetItemDocDetailID , 0 ) = isnull(t1.TargetItemDocDetailID,0)
```